# add a get variable django

Tags: django, url, get, django-templates

I have a (what I think) is a pretty basic question about appending a get variable to url in django. 
I have a filter sidebar on the page which creates a list of available classes based on the selection the user makes in the sidebar. For example, user may click on Aquatics class as a filter(other filters include things like location,price, time of day,etc) it will produce a list of aquatics classes available. Obviously, you can revise the search by choosing a specific location and now it should show  a list of aquatics classes in that location. 
what I would like is to make it so that every time use makes a choice, it adds a get variable to url like so: example.com/search?category=1&location=3. I'm not sure how I should go about it in the template. I know I need to get the list of variables by doing something like this

```
{% for k, v in request.GET.iteritems %}
    {{ k }}={{ v }}&
{% endfor %}
```

But I dont really know what to do next... Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you just trying to re-construct the original URL that the user requested? There are several methods hanging off the `request` object, `request.get_full_path()` being one that will return the path, plus an appended query string. [See the docs for additional methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this. `request.GET.urlencode`

That code automatically encode your GET parameter into URL friendly.